# Join 3 tables using a single Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, retailer,product and manufacturer.I will pass retailerID to the query and it should return the manufacturer Details.

```
criteria:
1)from the given input (retailerID) fetch productID from the retailer table.
2)Using productID get the manufacturerID from product table.
3)Get the complete details of manufacturer from manufacturer table using manufacturerID.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to show us some progress.

Comment: And also add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) And remember, if someone else does your homework, you won't learn much.

Comment: SELECT * FROM manufacturer where ManufacturerID = (select ManufacturerID from product 
where productID = ( select productID from retailer where retailerID = 1 ))

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Show your table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of your question, I understood that this is your requirement:

```
select * 
from manufacturer 
where manufacturerID = (
     select manufacturerID 
     from Product 
     where productID = (
         select productID 
         from retailer 
         where retailerID=@retailerID)
     )
```

Above query is written in subquery format, which can easily be converted into join format:

```
select * 
from Manufacturer m 
join Product p on m.manufacturerID = p.manufacturerID 
join retailer r on r.ProductID = p.ProductID
where r.RetailerID = @retailerID
```